# Failing to run Instrumented tests on a new Android Kotlin project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-instrumentation

I just created a new android application with `Kotlin` Support.

When I've tried to run the default instrumented tests it does not run and shows me this message:

```
Class not found: "oussaki.com.pos.ExampleInstrumentedTest"Empty test suite.
```

This the Instrumented test class that I'm trying to run:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class) 
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    fun useAppContext() {
        // Context of the app under test.
        val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()
        assertEquals("oussaki.com.pos", appContext.packageName)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check the device Logcat and post it here too. Usually this happens because of crashes on the test runner itself.

Comment: This error is not related to the device or any crash it's something related to Kotlin and  AndroidTests, there is no Log

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38452937 which hopefully will be fixed in the next release.

For the time being you can manually go to 'Edit Configurations' and add the configuration for the specific class/method you want to run under 'Android Instrumented Tests'.

You could also try the latest canary build: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html but personally I've had trouble getting it to work with my project.